# Move text in table into closest text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, css-selectors, closest

I have a table being dynamically built, and I need the text in column 2 in a text input instead. Once the text for that td is in a text input, remove the extra text outside of input. http://jsfiddle.net/NNpCB/

**HTML**

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='15'>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text2</td>
        <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text4</td>
        <td>text5</td>
        <td>text6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
valueCol = $("table#ruleTable tr td:nth-child(2)")
text = $(this).find().closest('td').text()

valueCol.append('<input type="text" value="' + text + '" />'); // add inputs with closest value
valueCol.text(''); // clear plain text from td once in inputs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNpCB/3/)**

```
var valueCol = $("table#ruleTable tr td:nth-child(2)");
valueCol.html(function () {
    return '<input value="' + $(this).text() + '"/>';

});
```

You can use `.append()` too, but it would be unnecessary task to append and clear text.